# generate pdf and embed in page with mpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am using [mPdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) to generate a pdf and it is working great.

```
function generate_pdf()
{
    $bom =$_POST["bom_contents"];
    $html = $this->load->view("public/print",array($bom),TRUE); //returns the html
    $this->load->library("mpdf");//loading the library
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html); //setting the html content to generate
    $this->mpdf->Output(); //send to browser
}
```

My html is as follows:

```
<div>
    <embed  id="doc" class="doc" src="what_i_put_here ?"></embed>
</div>
```

How can I set the src attribute of the embedded element, because mPdf is sending the content directly to the browser also I am using POST data, so that I cannot access it through URL.

Comment: What makes you use embed tag? Are you willing to embed your pdf?

Comment: @shubhansh i just want to show the generated pdf in page ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it to work .

When i click on Preview button ,it will show a notification that tells `Please wait generating pdf...` ,also i did a ajax request.

I generated a file using a ajax request and after that file creation i opened a popup,so that i can use the `src` attribute to the embed.

Answer (score 2):

Put your `generate_pdf()` function inside another file, such as pdf_generator.php.  Then set that file as the source:

```
<div>
    <embed  id="doc" class="doc" src="pdf_generator.php<?=$_POST["bom_contents"];?>"></embed>
</div>
```

Updated function:

```
function generate_pdf()
{
    $bom =$_GET["bom_contents"];
    $html = $this->load->view("public/print",array($bom),TRUE); //returns the html
    $this->load->library("mpdf");//loading the library
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html); //setting the html content to generate
    $this->mpdf->Output(); //send to browser
}
```

Comment: How can i send the post data to the file ?

Comment: I'm assuming since the `$_POST` content is output back to the user in the PDF that you don't need to keep it hidden, and so using `$_GET` shouldn't be a problem.  I've updated my original answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: thats a way ..but its lengthy.contain arrays of data.